# PHP openssl_encrypt Reponse doesn't match CryptoJS AES Encryption

Tags: javascript, php, encryption, cryptojs

PHP Encryption Logic

```php
$secret_key = '###$$**@@@//!!!^^%%%';
$secret_iv = '$$##!!&&**!!**@@';

$encrypt_method = "AES-256-CBC";
$key = hash('sha256', $secret_key); // d7cc77e5a8db446cc11aaa510b5191852a0084ad09f7b33623137c78e09c8050
$iv = substr(hash('sha256', $secret_iv), 0, 16); // 36a50210c8b2f19e

$output = openssl_encrypt('testingDemo', $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
// response --> uRfctdzWekUYISdKHKW88Q==
```

JS Encryption Logic

```js
const SECRET_KEY = '###$$**@@@//!!!^^%%%';
const SECRET_IV = '$$##!!&&**!!**@@';
const key = SHA256(SECRET_KEY); // d7cc77e5a8db446cc11aaa510b5191852a0084ad09f7b33623137c78e09c8050
const iv = SHA256(SECRET_IV).toString().substr(0, 16); // 36a50210c8b2f19e
console.log(iv, 'iv....');
const encrypted = AES.encrypt('testingDemo', key, { iv: enc.Hex.parse(iv) });
console.log(encrypted.toString(enc.Base64) // response --> vXyYVoSYagBbN0ihXVTgaA==
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Please somebody help.

=============================
**Update. The Working Code**

JS Encryption Logic

```js
export const tokenGenerator = (subdomain) => {
  const plainText = `${atob(process.env.REACT_APP_PREFIX)}${subdomain}${atob(process.env.REACT_APP_SUFFIX)}`;
  const key = SHA256(atob(process.env.REACT_APP_SECRET_KEY)).toString().substr(0, 32);
  const iv = SHA256(atob(process.env.REACT_APP_SECRET_IV)).toString().substr(0, 16);
  const encrypted = AES.encrypt(plainText, enc.Utf8.parse(key), { iv: enc.Utf8.parse(iv) });
  return btoa(enc.Base64.stringify(encrypted.ciphertext));
};
```

PHP Encryption Logic

```php
$secret_key = '###$$**@@@//!!!^^%%%';
$secret_iv = '$$##!!&&**!!**@@';
$encrypt_method = "AES-256-CBC";
$key = hash('sha256', $secret_key);
$iv = substr(hash('sha256', $secret_iv), 0, 16);
$output = openssl_encrypt('testingDemo', $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
```

Comment: Should the 3rd parameter of the [`hash`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) function not be set to true in the PHP code? Then, for compatibility the hashed IV needs to be used in the CryptoJS code, directly as `WordArray`. CryptoJS implicitly considers only the first 16 bytes of the 32 bytes (although it is cleaner to shorten the IV to 16 bytes). Otherwise (if the PHP code remains unchanged) you have to hex encode key and IV in the CryptoJS code, shorten the key to 32, the IV to 16 bytes and convert both back to a `WordArray` with Utf8.

Comment: Papu Kumar: kindly share your final javascript and PHP-codes so that others can benefit from the solution provided by @Topaco.

Comment: @MichaelFehr OP updated with the solution.